# Navigating to a different view - pushViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a tableview, and when i click on a row, it navigates to another view; The code for the navigation part is shown below;

```
ShowImageController *showImageController = [[HowItWorksViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:showImageController  animated:YES];
```

The other view contains an image, i have added the image to its viewDidLoad. and here's the code for that

```
 UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"hello.png"]];
    [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(o, o, 200, 300)];

[[self view] addSubview:imageView ];
```

The problem is When i click on the row it takes a long time (extremely slow), to navigate to the other screen.

note: Rows which didn't have an image in the other view navigated well with no issue. Why is this happening ? and how can i fix it ?

Comment: this may be due to the size of the image .. try the same code in viewWillAppear

Comment: The size of the image is 15kb

Comment: 15kb doesn't sounds too big, but I can't see what else the problem is other that what you're seeing. Try my code in my answer to see if it helps by loading it on a background thread.

Comment: Its not the image size. Are you getting any external data from server ?

Comment: No its not coming from the server. I have the image saved in my project

Comment: I would suggest to test your code with a different smaller-sized image. Now see if it works fine or not. Also, try the code adding the image through xib. In this way, you can be sure whether it is image size-related problem or some other issue.

Comment: @OP Hmm, since others comments are not helping, then add some NSLog seem where it has been stuck...

Answer (score 0):

Definitely sounds like the images are big and therefore taking a while to load. I suggest you either use smaller images or if you have no control over them you might want to try loading the images in the background. Here is some code to get you started with loading them in the background:

```
- (void)decodeImageInBackgroundThread:(UIImage*)decodedImage forImageView:(UIImageView*)imageView {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
        CGImageRef originalImage = [decodedImage CGImage];

        CFDataRef imageData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(originalImage));
        CGDataProviderRef imageDataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(imageData);

        if (imageData != NULL) {
            CFRelease(imageData);
        }

        CGImageRef image = CGImageCreate(CGImageGetWidth(originalImage),
                                         CGImageGetHeight(originalImage),
                                         CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(originalImage),
                                         CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(originalImage),
                                         CGImageGetBytesPerRow(originalImage),
                                         CGImageGetColorSpace(originalImage),
                                         CGImageGetBitmapInfo(originalImage),
                                         imageDataProvider,
                                         CGImageGetDecode(originalImage),
                                         CGImageGetShouldInterpolate(originalImage),
                                         CGImageGetRenderingIntent(originalImage));

        if (imageDataProvider != NULL) {
            CGDataProviderRelease(imageDataProvider);
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:image]];
            CGImageRelease(image);
        });
    });
}
```

Which you can then use like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    ...

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hello.png"];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:nil];
    [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 200.0f, 300.0f)];
    [[self view] addSubview:imageView];

    [self decodeImageInBackgroundThread:image forImageView:imageView];
}
```

Comment: It says that there are few parameters, and it points to `(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW),`. Any idea how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the images in a asynk task or nsoperationqueue :)